# how to shift osticket from one server to another without reinstalling?

Tags: php, mysql, config, osticket

I am running osTicket on server and now i need to migrate the server. So i took backup of files and database on my localhost and trying to run it for test but it is giving me error of 500 and descripton is

> PHP Fatal error:  Can't inherit abstract function AuthenticatedUser::getId() (previously declared abstract in BaseAuthenticatedUser) in /var/www/html/ostickets/upload/include/class.auth.php on line 26

I am testing it on local so that after successful migration i don't want to loose any of my data. please guide.

Comment: please anyone... if can give any link regarding, would be great help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple, once you've installed the same version of OSTicket in your new server, you just need to migrate the database.

From terminal:

```
mysql -u root -p ost_db < [PATH TO YOU OSTicket DB BACKUP FILE]/ost_db.sql
```

Have a great day!

Comment: Just a quick clarification, all the configuration data etc is in the DB? so only backup of DB is required?

Comment: exactly! so it's good practice to regularly `mysqldump ost_db > ost_db.sql` (backup)